# Program to print directories using c not working, issues with recursive call

Tags: c, linux, shell, directory-structure, ls

I need to create a program that basically acts similarly to the list utility on Linux. I've been trying to get this to work and I'm pretty close but now I've gotten stuck. Essentially it will print whatever files and sub-directories that are contained withing a directory(i.e. if i run ./project3, it lists whatevers in that directory). However, once I try to get the recursive call working it spits out something like:

```
sh: 1: /home/RageKage/Documents/Project3/dir1: Permission denied
```

That's where I'm stuck, I'm not exactly sure what to do from here. I'm getting the path of the directory to explore using realpath and that works fine, but the recursive call just isn't working and I'm not exactly sure what I'm doing wrong. Any help would be appreciated as I'm relatively new to this.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <dirent.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <limits.h>

int main (int argc, char *argv[])
{
    DIR *dir;
    struct dirent *sd;
    const char *direct;
    char buf[PATH_MAX + 1];

    if (argc < 2)
    {
        direct = ".";
    }else{
        direct = argv[1];
        //printf("Hey this is argv[1]:  %s\n", argv[1]);
    }


    dir = opendir(direct);

    if (dir == NULL)
    {
        printf("ERROR! NO DIRECTORY TO OPEN!\n");
        exit(1);
    }

    while( (sd=readdir(dir)) != NULL )
    {

        if (!strcmp(sd->d_name, ".") || !strcmp(sd->d_name, ".."))
        {

        }else{
            printf("\n>> %s\n", sd->d_name);
        }


        if (!strcmp(sd->d_name, "..") ||  !strcmp(sd->d_name, "."))
        {

        }else if (sd->d_type == 4){
            printf("Attempting to Run!\n");

            realpath(sd->d_name, buf);
            printf("[%s]\n", buf);

            system(("./project3 %s", buf));
            printf("\n");

        }

    }


    closedir(dir);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Where's the recursion?

Comment: ```realpath(sd->d_name, buf);

    system(buf);
```

buf contains the real path to the directory plus I believe the command used to start the program, so something like ./project3  /home/RageKageDocuments/Project3/dir3. At least thats what I get when I print buf.

Comment: Really? What's the exact output you get when you run this program?

Comment: Im not sure how to post the output so I took a screenshot if that helps [link](http://imgur.com/FRSaSe3)

Comment: That says nothing about `./project3` being in `buf`.

Comment: yeah you're right, okay then I have no idea whats going on anymore. What I want to happen is for this program to call itself again whenever it hits a directory and explore that and all sub-directories within that sub-directory and eventually return. I changed the code so that it reads `system(("./project3 %s", buf));` but now I get [this](http://imgur.com/3FgRMHn)

Comment: That's the same as `system(buf)`. The comma operator throws away the result of its first operand and returns the second operand.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
system(("./project3 %s", buf));
```

Are you recursively calling the program itself again? That sounds a bit inefficient, and hard to do since you'd need to know where the executable file is. In general it could be just about anywhere (starting with `/bin`, `/usr/bin` etc.), and all you are likely to get in `argv[0]` is the filename part, not the whole path.

Also, as said in the comments, `func((this, that))` is the same as `func(that)`, not `func(this, that)`, since the parenthesis make the comma act as the comma operator, not as an argument separator. And `system()` only takes one argument anyway, so you'd need to use `sprintf()` to build the command line. (Or perhaps use the `exec()` functions to actually give separate arguments without invoking a shell, but then you need to do the `fork()`, too.)

I'd suggest scrapping that idea, and putting the directory tree walking into a function of it's own, and calling that recursively:

```
void walkpath(void)
{
    DIR *dir = opendir(".");
    struct dirent *sd;
    while((sd = readdir(dir)) != NULL) {
        /* ... */
        if (sd->d_type == DT_DIR) {
            chdir(sd->d_name);
            walkpath();
            chdir("..");
        }
    }
}
int main(...)
{
     /* ... */
     chdir(directory);
     walkpath();
}
```

I used `chdir` here to change the process's working directory along with the walk. If you need to track the full directory name, then you'll need to add that.

Also, now you have the test for `.` and `..` twice. Use `continue` to end that iteration of the loop so you don't need to test the same thing again.

```
if (strcmp(sd->d_name, ".") == 0 || strcmp(sd->d_name, "..") == 0) {
    continue;
}
```

Comment: This helped a ton! Recursively calling the program again was causing a ton of issues so I did what you suggested and split the program up. I wrote it different to what you posted but the end result was the same. Many thanks!